# Store user sessions: node.js, express, mongoose-auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a newbie node.js question about authentication ans sessions.

I've made an authentication with: express.js and mongoose-auth (mongodb):

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'esoognom'}));
app.use(auth.mongooseAuth.middleware());
```

I've got not much understanding of all that staff deeply. After users are authenticated they stay to be so unless server restarts. I want to have more persistent state of authentication, how can I manage this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the sessions to persist even after a server has crashes / restarted then you should use one of the following modules:

- [connect-redis](http://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) (in memory db, which is usually used) < sessions are stored in a Redis db
- [connect-mongodb](http://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb) < sessions stored in MongoDB
- other session stores found here, such as couchdb or memcached: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki

You can also set the lifetime of a cookie using the maxAge param when adding the session middleware. For example if we were using connect-mongodb:

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret : "Stays my secret",
    maxAge : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //1 Hour
    store  : new MongoStore({ db: 'myDB' })
}));
```

Comment: But what I didn't understand is how to make user login state save (with mongoose-auth)  event after the server restart. After server restarts req.user is undefined.

Comment: Use either MongoStore or RedisStore like I've said in the message above. Both should keep the session variables even after restart, unless you are expressly deleting them or setting an expiry date too soon (!).

Comment: In https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb there is mongodb module connection setup is required, can I make it with mongoose?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Either way, better do them separate.

Comment: Broken link for connect-mongodb

Answer (score 2):

If you use a mongostore it will persist for longer than a server restart.

This is configurable with the maxAge property. It defaults to `14400000` which I believe is in ms, so 4 hours.

See the documentation for details:
http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using express V2.5.11. Here the maxAge option is not seems to be working. So I rewrite session configure code as follows.

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
app.use(express.session({
    secret : "basic server",
    cookie : {
        maxAge : 20000 //20 seconds
    }, 
    //maxAge:  new Date(Date.now() + 20000),
    store : new MongoStore({
        host : 'localhost',
        port : 27017,
        db : 'yourdb',
        collection : 'session',
        stringify : false,
        clear_interval : (10)//search db to clear the expired every 10 seconds  
    })
}));
```

The code is working as pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

Authentication Using Passport

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
api = require('./routes/api'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
mysql = require('mysql'),
passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

//MySQL

var sqlInfo = {
    host: 'localhost', 
    user: 'root',
    password: '', 
    database: 'dbname'
}


global.client = mysql.createConnection(sqlInfo);

client.connect();




var app = module.exports = express();




/**
 * Configuration
 */

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.cookieParser("secret"));
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(app.router);




passport.use(new LocalStrategy(

    function(username, password, done) {

        return check_auth_user(username,password,done);

    }

    ));


// development only
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// production only
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
// TODO
}



/**
 * routes start---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
// home page contain login form 
app.get('/home', function(reg, res){
    //check user session value, is logged in 
    if(req.user)
        res.render('dash',{
            username: req.user['member_id']//req.user array contains serializeUser data
        });
    else
        res.render('index');

});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/home');
});

//login form submit as post

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/home'
    })
    );
//to project dashboard
app.get('/dash',routes.dash);
//to project dashboard
app.get('/signup',routes.signup);
//to project dashboard

app.get('*', routes.index);

/**
 * routes end---------------------------------------------------------------------
 */


/**
 * Start Server
 */

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

[click for more details with example](http://www.crashcoder.com/nodejs-user-autentication-and-session-storage-using-express-mysql-passport/)